# Retrofit with proguard is not deserializing some models

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2, android-proguard

In my code `User` model is not being unserialized despite being returned by the server. From my code `client.getPerson()` returns an instance of the `Person` object but `client.getUser()` returns an empty string
What could be the problem?

My `Client` class as follows,

```
public class Client implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("address")
private String address;

@SerializedName("nhif_no")
private String nhifNo;

@SerializedName("occupation_name")
private String occupationName;

@SerializedName("person")
private Person person;

@SerializedName("kra_pin")
private String kraPin;

@SerializedName("user")
private User user;

@SerializedName("client_id")
private int clientId;

@SerializedName("sales_agent_id")
private int salesAgentId;

public void setAddress(String address){
    this.address = address;
}

public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}

public void setNhifNo(String nhifNo){
    this.nhifNo = nhifNo;
}

public String getNhifNo(){
    return nhifNo;
}

public void setOccupationName(String occupationName){
    this.occupationName = occupationName;
}

public String getOccupationName(){
    return occupationName;
}

public void setPerson(Person person){
    this.person = person;
}

public Person getPerson(){
    return person;
}

public void setKraPin(String kraPin){
    this.kraPin = kraPin;
}

public String getKraPin(){
    return kraPin;
}

public void setUser(User user){
    this.user = user;
}

public User getUser(){
    return user;
}

public void setClientId(int clientId){
    this.clientId = clientId;
}

public int getClientId(){
    return clientId;
}

public void setSalesAgentId(int salesAgentId){
    this.salesAgentId = salesAgentId;
}

public int getSalesAgentId(){
    return salesAgentId;
}
}
```

My `Person` class as follows,

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("last_name")
private String lastName;

@SerializedName("middle_name")
private String middleName;

@SerializedName("first_name")
private String firstName;

@SerializedName("person_id")
private int personId;

public void setLastName(String lastName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName){
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public String getMiddleName(){
    return middleName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public void setPersonId(int personId){
    this.personId = personId;
}

public int getPersonId(){
    return personId;
}
}
```

My `User` class as follows,

```
public class User implements Serializable{

@SerializedName("role_id")
private int roleId;

@SerializedName("email")
private String email;

public void setRoleId(int roleId){
    this.roleId = roleId;
}

public int getRoleId(){
    return roleId;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}
}
```

My JSON file as follows,

`{
    "client": {
        "client_id": 128,
        "nhif_no": "KJNH1289",
        "kra_pin": "210986",
        "sales_agent_id": 43,
        "address": "Kikuyu",
        "occupation_name": "Prisoner",
        "person": {
            "person_id": 358,
            "first_name": "Kamiti",
            "middle_name": "Jela",
            "last_name": "Baridi",
            "gender": {
                "gender_id": 1,
                "name": "Male"
            }
        },
        "user": {
            "email": "jelabaridi@gmail.com",
            "role_id": 2
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the line below in the proguard rules file

`-keep class org.myapp.mypackage.models.** { *; }`